# Delay ios permissions notification on app startup?

Tags: ios, notifications, startup, ios-permissions

We would like to play an intro for our camera app but the "would like to access your cameraroll" notification is killing our steaze. Anyone know how to delay these? Thanks!

Comment: Don't try to access the camera roll until after the video completes.

Answer (score 0):

Use this NSTimer method to delay the execution of a method...

```
+ (NSTimer *)scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds target:(id)target selector:(SEL)aSelector userInfo:(id)userInfo repeats:(BOOL)repeats
```

In your case put something like this in your AppDelegate.m...

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
     [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:delayTimeInSeconds target:self selector:@selector(promptForCameraRollAccessIfNecessaryMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot imagine a scenario where @rmaddy's comment is not the answer. So points go to @rmaddy. above.

Just don't access the camera or ask for permissions until your other cases have completed.